# Update table from CSV data

Tags: javascript, node.js

After importing CSV data and converting it into json object (editarray).
I want to update table rows accordingly.

[image: Table structure]
Should I convert the keys of editarray into an individual array (like taskArray, customerEmailArray, customerNameArray ) and then update or is there any other way around?

```
var editArray = [ { 'Task Id*': '279620',
    customer_email: 'john@gmail.com',
    customer_name: 'John Snow',
    tags: '' 

  },
  { 'Task Id*': '279614',
    customer_email: 'joe@gmail.com',
    customer_name: 'Joey Tribianni',
    tags: '' 

  } 
]

var taskArray = editArray.map(a=>{
      var taskId        =  a["Task Id*"];
      return taskId;
  });

  var customerEmailArray = editArray.map(a=>{     
      var customerEmail        = a["customer_email"];
      return customerEmail;
  });

  var customerNameArray = editArray.map(a=>{
      var customerName        =  a["customer_name"];
      return customerName;
  });  
console.log(taskArray, customerEmailArray, customerNameArray);
```

Comment: which database ?

Comment: kindly check the edit @UsmanRana

Comment: it's mysql right ?

Comment: Yes it is mysql